# How can i check form is open in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

I want to write a simple c# windows application for this plan:
when then form load timer starts, check and show any another form,i have two forms,form one start timer 1 and timer 1 start form 2 with this code:

```
ShowALARM frm = new ShowALARM();
frm.Show();
frm.listBox1.Items.Add(x);
```

up code call with timer method,with per call that code,open new form!,i want to  check to see if form is open, however, if false then run the new form.how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all open forms with code `Application.OpenForms`. To find particular form is open you can do this `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Any()` where `From1` is form you are looking for.

One piece of advice - do not write code like this: `frm.listBox1.Items.Add(x);` as you are breaking SoC (separation of concerns). One form should not know much about any other. Much better is to create a method on targeted form like `AddItem(object x)` and call it from other forms.

Code sample:

```
protected void TimerTickMethod()
{
   if (!IsShowALARMFormOpened())
   {
      ShowALARM frm = new ShowALARM();
      frm.Show();
   }
}

protected bool IsShowALARMFormOpened()
{
    return Application.OpenForms.OfType<ShowALARM>().Any();
}
```